# fluentnhibernate ManyToMany does not add records to the junction table

Tags: many-to-many, fluent-nhibernate

When saving my many-to-many related entities, the entities are saved ok. However the junction table stays empty:

Mapping on Product side (ProductMap.cs)

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Pictures)
.Table("Product_Picture")
.ParentKeyColumn("Product")
.ChildKeyColumn("Picture")
.Cascade.All()
.Inverse()
```

This produces the following xml:

```
<bag cascade="all" name="Pictures" table="Product_Picture">
  <key>
    <column name="Product" />
  </key>
  <many-to-many class="...Picture...">
    <column name="Picture" />
  </many-to-many>
</bag>
```

Mapping on Picture side (PictureMap.cs)

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Products)
.Table("Product_Picture")
.ParentKeyColumn("Picture")
.ChildKeyColumn("Product")
.Cascade.All();
```

This produces the following xml:

```
<bag inverse="true" cascade="all" name="Products" table="Product_Picture">
  <key>
    <column name="Picture" />
  </key>
  <many-to-many class="...Product...">
    <column name="Product" />
  </many-to-many>
</bag>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need a blank line before you start a code block.

Comment: ok thanks :), now I only need an answer to the question

Comment: As I've suggested, we're going to need to see some more code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make sure you are adding to the collection on the `Picture` object, which is the direction of the relationship you have not declared as `Inverse()`. Adding to the other side of the relationship will not cause them to be persisted.

If you are doing this, or are adding to both sides, then please post some of the code where you are manipulating and trying to save these objects.

Comment: They are added to both sides. That should be ok too?

Comment: I have set this as an answer. 
The problem is a bit more complicated, and this anwer helped me conclude that there was nothing wrong with the mappings, but that I had to look elsewhere.